# How to add 2 lines of label on X axis on Fusion Chart?

Tags: fusioncharts

The purpose is to have 2 lines of text on the X axis for each bar. 
e.g
JUN

2018

and style each line in a different way ( like color the year label in green ) .

Can we do it? 
This is how I populate the bars in a custom way.

```
str += '<set label="' + months[i].toUpperCase() + ' ' + currentyear + '" value="' + amount + '" color="08cf77" toolText="' + cur_symbol + amount + '"  />\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
 '&#10;'
```

So the line should be updated as;

```
str += '<set label="' + months[i].toUpperCase() + '&#10;' + currentyear + '" value="' + amount + '" color="08cf77" toolText="' + cur_symbol + amount + '" />\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

A multi-axis line chart is an interactive line chart that plots data using multiple axes. This allows plotting data sets having different units and scale ranges. Data values are plotted as data points that are connected by line segments.

```
    const dataSource = {
  chart: {
    caption: "IBRD Subscriptions and Voting Powers",
    subcaption: "For OECD countries",
    showvalues: "0",
    labeldisplay: "ROTATE",
    rotatelabels: "1",
    plothighlighteffect: "fadeout",
    plottooltext: "$seriesName in $label : <b>$dataValue</b>",
    theme: "candy"
  },
  axis: [
    {
      title: "Subscription Amount",
      titlepos: "left",
      numberprefix: "$",
      divlineisdashed: "1",
      maxvalue: "100000",
      dataset: [
        {
          seriesname: "Subscription Amount",
          linethickness: "3",
          data: [
            {
              value: "38450.2"
            },
            {
              value: "16544.4"
            },
            {
              value: "10659.4"
            },
            {
              value: "9657.4"
            },
            {
              value: "9040.4"
            },
            {
              value: "9040.4"
            },
            {
              value: "6992.3"
            },
            {
              value: "6650.5"
            },
            {
              value: "6650.5"
            },
            {
              value: "6337.2"
            },
            {
              value: "5835.4"
            },
            {
              value: "4582.9"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "Subscription %",
      axisonleft: "1",
      titlepos: "left",
      numdivlines: "8",
      divlineisdashed: "1",
      maxvalue: "25",
      numbersuffix: "%",
      dataset: [
        {
          seriesname: "Subscription %",
          dashed: "1",
          data: [
            {
              value: "17.23"
            },
            {
              value: "7.41"
            },
            {
              value: "4.78"
            },
            {
              value: "4.33"
            },
            {
              value: "4.05"
            },
            {
              value: "4.05"
            },
            {
              value: "3.13"
            },
            {
              value: "2.98"
            },
            {
              value: "2.98"
            },
            {
              value: "2.84"
            },
            {
              value: "2.62"
            },
            {
              value: "2.05"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "Number of Votes",
      titlepos: "RIGHT",
      axisonleft: "0",
      numdivlines: "5",
      numbersuffix: "",
      divlineisdashed: "1",
      maxvalue: "400000",
      dataset: [
        {
          seriesname: "Number of Votes",
          linethickness: "3",
          data: [
            {
              value: "358196"
            },
            {
              value: "166138"
            },
            {
              value: "107288"
            },
            {
              value: "97268"
            },
            {
              value: "91098"
            },
            {
              value: "91098"
            },
            {
              value: "70617"
            },
            {
              value: "67199"
            },
            {
              value: "67199"
            },
            {
              value: "64066"
            },
            {
              value: "59048"
            },
            {
              value: "46523"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "Voting %",
      titlepos: "RIGHT",
      axisonleft: "0",
      numdivlines: "5",
      divlineisdashed: "1",
      maxvalue: "20",
      numbersuffix: "%",
      dataset: [
        {
          seriesname: "Voting %",
          dashed: "1",
          data: [
            {
              value: "16.3"
            },
            {
              value: "7.03"
            },
            {
              value: "4.54"
            },
            {
              value: "4.12"
            },
            {
              value: "3.86"
            },
            {
              value: "3.86"
            },
            {
              value: "2.99"
            },
            {
              value: "2.84"
            },
            {
              value: "2.84"
            },
            {
              value: "2.71"
            },
            {
              value: "2.5"
            },
            {
              value: "1.97"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  categories: [
    {
      category: [
        {
          label: "2006"
        },
        {
          label: "2007"
        },
        {
          label: "2008"
        },
        {
          label: "2009"
        },
        {
          label: "2010"
        },
        {
          label: "2011"
        },
        {
          label: "2012"
        },
        {
          label: "2013"
        },
        {
          label: "2014"
        },
        {
          label: "2015"
        },
        {
          label: "2016"
        },
        {
          label: "2017"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var myChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: "multiaxisline",
    renderAt: "chart-container",
    width: "100%",
    height: "500",
    dataFormat: "json",
    dataSource
  }).render();
});
```

Here is the demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/7fyvnrqz/

Additionally, if you want to add separator line then you can use Vertical or horizontal in case of bar charts:

```
{
    "vline": "true",
    "showOnTop": "1",
    "label": "Weekend Start",
    "linePosition": "0.7",
    "labelPosition": "0.5"
}
```

To know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/vertical-lines